# How to take proper care of a Javanese Jungle Scorpion?

Tags: adoption, exotic-pets, scorpions

My local pet store has recently brought an adult Javanese Jungle Scorpion. It is very beautiful and I am planning to buy it. Please advice me on how to set up proper environment and properly take care of my scorpion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javanese Jungle Scorpion belongs to the class of tropical forest scorpions.

**Housing -**

Take a fish tank of 10 gallon with lockable lead. Scorpions are great escape artists and can squeeze through very small opening. Also they can lift loosely fit light leads.

**Substrate -**

About 5 inches of substrate should be provided at the bottom of the tank. Sterilized earth can be used as substrate.

**Hiding space -**

Scorpions are by nature very shy animals and they require some hiding place where they can feel safe from predators. Use substance that fulfill the purpose as you will. For example, pieces of wood and ceramic will serve good.

**Water dish -**

Keep a sallow water dish for water to drink. The water should not be too deep that it can drown the scorpion.

**Heating -**

Don't use overhead heating lights. Scorpions tend to avoid light and they will hide all day. Use heat mat. Keep the heat mat at one side of the tank to create a temperature gradient. Don't keep the heat mat under tank as it may lead to overheating. Use thermometer to maintain optimal temperature. About 25 degree C is ideal.

**Feeding -**

Buy live cricket at pet store and keep them in a tank. Feed them with cricket food available at pet store and online. This is called gut loading (you make the cricket more nutritious). Feed the scorpion a cricket 3 to 5 days apart. Use mealworm as occasional treats. As it is nocturnal feed at night.

**Handling -**

Javanese Jungle Scorpion gives a very benign sting. So it is OK to handle it. Do it very gently and try to watch some online videos regarding handling of scorpions.

**Cleaning -**

Clean the food remains every 3 to 4 days. Every 3 to 4 months change the substrate completely and disinfect the tank using an arachnid friendly disinfectant. Once your scorpion molds you will also need to remove the shed skin.